# mysql WHERE multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

i have a Problem using WHERE in my Select query.
The DB-table contains a field that stores data divided by a comma like "1,2,3".
I dont know how to check if the field contains 1,2 or 3. The usual query would be 
"SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE name = '".$val."'".
But of course this only finds entries that equal $val, so if I search for "1" it will only give me the entries only containing "1", not "1,2,3" or "1,2". Is there a way to do that?

Thanks guys

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should fix your data structure.  There are lots of good reasons to avoid storing lists of numbers as strings:

- Values should be stored as their correct data types.  Numbers are not strings.
- SQL has pretty poor string processing functionality.
- SQL has this great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a table.
- If the numbers refer to another table, then you cannot declare proper foreign key relationships.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  In those cases, MySQL offers [`find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
where find_in_set(1, name) > 0
```